# Mathieu functions calculation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request, special-functions

I am currently working in MATLAB (this is not relevant to the question, though), and MATLAB doesn't have built-in Mathieu functions (such as the Mathieu cosine and sine).

In principle this is just fine, because I can generate them with a RK or predictor corrector method. However, this calculates all the points in the function up to a certain $x$, and that is not very efficient if I'm only interested in one specific $f(x_i)$, for a given $x_i$.

Could you provide references with explicit algorithms to calculate the Mathieu sine and cosine functions? Any other comments or suggestions are of course also welcome.

**Edit**: to clarify, I'm looking to generate the functions as defined [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MathieuFunction.html) or [here](http://dlmf.nist.gov/28.2#ii) (where they are referred as basic solutions). I'm not looking for the periodic solutions, but the (normalized) odd and even fundamental solutions of the equation
$$
\ddot{x} + (a - 2q\cos 2 \tau)x = 0
$$
and also the characteristic exponent $\nu(a,q)$

Comment: Mathematica has them, but I don't know how it is implemented there.

Comment: Have a look at the nice paper (http://users.df.uba.ar/sgil/physics_paper_doc/papers_phys/modern/matheiu0.pdf) where you will find (in an Appendix) a way for calculating the coefficients in a series development.

Comment: Notations and names vary, could you clarify what you are looking for in the terms used by the [Digital Library of Mathematical Functions](http://dlmf.nist.gov/28.1)? I assume you are referring to $\mathrm{ce}_{\nu}(z,q)$ for the Mathieu cosine, and $\mathrm{se}_{\nu}(z,q)$ for the Mathieu sine? I own a slim volume, Malcolm M. Bibby, Andrew F. Peterson, "Accurate Computation of Mathieu Functions" (2013), but I haven't actually worked through it so cannot vouch for quality. The already mentioned DLMF has a short section on computational aspects.

Comment: Another approach is to use their Fourier series, as described in the DLMF here: http://dlmf.nist.gov/28.4.

Comment: This might be of help: Danilo Erricolo, "Algorithm 861: Fortran 90 Subroutines for Computing the Expansion Coefficients of Mathieu Functions Using Blanch’s Algorithm", *ACM Transactions on Mathematical Software*, Vol. 32, No. 4, December 2006, pp. 622-634 ([online; incl. source code for download](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1186793))

Comment: @gerd You might want to indicate need for real vs complex parameterized implementations. Also of potential interest: Danilo Erricolo and Giuseppe Carluccio, "Algorithm 934: Fortran 90 Subroutines to Compute Mathieu Functions for Complex Values of the Parameter", *ACM Transactions on Mathematical Software*, Vol. 40, No. 1, Article 8, September 2013 ([online, incl. source code](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2513117))